# Jenkins ⇔ Github-Webhook setup for multiple repositories

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, github-enterprise

In order for Jenkins to be able to have access to multiple repositories on the same server, I set the `.ssh/config` as follow:

```
Host a.github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/project-a-id_rsa

# same for other repos
```

and set the Jenkins jobs' *Source Code Management* (SCM), to `git` and `git@a.github.com:user/repo_a.git`. It works fine.

**Problem**
I want those jobs to be triggered on push events so I set a webhook service in github, .i.e, *Jenkins (GitHub plugin)*. The request received from the webhook are "POST for https://github.com/user/repo_a" which is a different host than the one set in the SCM, .i.e, `a.github.com`.
Because they are different, the job does not build automatically.

**Ugly Solution**
I got something running by setting the SCM to `github.com` and override the remote url of the project's git config once cloned with `a.github.com`. So the SCM would match the webhook, and jenkins when running `git push` would use the `.ssh/config` info.

**Question**
What else can I do ? Is there a better, easily automated way to achieve this?

Comment: I have the same problem. I am getting timeout errors on the github webhooks page and I think it is because I am using private repos (so ssh keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped using the `deploy key` and added my own account credentials on jenkins to be able to deal with all repositories without having to change the host with `.ssh/config`.